# How to write the same variable x times to file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

This is my script right now:

```
[int]$NumberOfProfiles = Read-Host "Enter the number of profiles You need"
 $WhereToWrite = Read-Host "Enter the full path where You'd like to install the profiles" 

$Source = Get-Location 
$FolderName = "Fish"
$SourceDirectory = "$Source\$Foldername"

$Variable1 = "Plane"
$Variable2 = "Car"
...
$Variable100 = "Boat"

while ($NumberOfProfiles -gt 0) {
  $DestinationDirectory = Join-Path $WhereToWrite "$Foldername$NumberOfProfiles"
  $PrefsDirectory = "$DestinationDirectory\Data\profile\prefs.js"
$Changer = Get-Variable -Name "Variable$NumberOfProfiles" -ValueOnly 
  Copy-Item $SourceDirectory $DestinationDirectory -Recurse -Container
    Write-Host "Made a new profile to" $DestinationDirectory
        (Get-Content $PrefsDirectory) | %{$_.Replace("SomeInfo", "Changer")} | Set-Content $PrefsDirectory 
$NumberOfProfiles--
}
```

The thing I'd like to achieve is that I'd write $Variable1 to the five first copied folders and so on.

E.g. it would look something like that: "Plane" in prefs.js in Fish1, Fish2, Fish3, Fish4, Fish5. "Car" in prefs.js in Fish6, Fish7, Fish8, Fish9, Fish10 and so on.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: If you *must* use 100 variables, use an [array](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the values into an array, and use the array index to choose which one to write.

I have no idea how you've got the folders enumerated, but this will increment the value array index ($ValIdx) once for every 5 folder increments ($i), through 500 folder increments:

```
$values = ("15","45"..."72")
$ValIdx = 0

for ($i = 1;$i -le 500;$i++)
 {
   '{0} {1}' -f $i,$ValIdx  #Write $Values[$ValIdx] to $folders[$i] here
   $valIdx += -not ($i % 5)
}
```

Explanation - The modulo operator (%) returns the remainder of a division operation.  ($i % 5) is dividing $i by 5, and returning the remainder.  The -not is evaluating that as a Boolean (true/false) and returning the opposite value.   $ValIdx is an [int], so that Boolean value is being coerced to an [int] for the += operation.

When $i is a multiple of 5, ($i % 5) is zero, which will cast to [bool] as $false.  The -not will flip that to $true. If it's not a multiple of 5, ($i % 5) will return some non-zero value, which will cast to $true, and get flipped to $false.

When the Boolean is cast as [int] for the += operation, it becomes 1 for $true or 0 for $false.  The end result is that every time $i hits a multiple of 5, $ValIdx gets incremented by 1.  If it's not multiple of 5, $ValIdx gets incremented by 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The folders were enumerated with $DestinationDirectory. But aren't there any way to do this with variables because actually the length of my variables are damn long so it's quite PITA to put them all into array. (To illustrate a length of one variable - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Avant TriCore) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"

Comment: It's possible, but imposes a huge amount of overhead and is just plain bad practice. If they're that long, I'd think you'd have them stored in a file, and would just do a $values = get-content <values file>.

Comment: Okey. But could You by any chance elaborate the code in Your answer? I can't seem to understand it fully as I am still a beginner.

Comment: Added am explanation to the answer.

Comment: Hey! But how could I change it so that when the $i divided by 5 then it already increases the $Validx for the $values. E.g. $i = 6 then it takes "15" from the $values array first, next $i = 5 and it takes "45" . It doesn't work for me because of the while loop I have and the Read-Host I use with $NumberOfProfiles right now. Image to illustrate - http://i.stack.imgur.com/IpRHl.png